# Common name for inverse of beta reduction

Tags: terminology, lambda-calculus

For some transformation, I am currently working on, it is useful to "pull out" subexpressions and replacing them with variables.

i.e. $\textbf{transform}(42 + 3 * 4) = (\lambda x. 42 + x) (3*4)$

This has, of course, the same result (if it does not extract bound variables and is correct only modulo evaluation order, i.e. termination properties might change).

Such a basic operation probably has an established name, but I never heard it. Is it "beta-expansion"?

Comment: Isn't this called abstraction? I do not mean the syntactic category, but transformation: you "abstract over" the right summand of the sum expression.

Comment: Wouldn't "abstraction" mean to leave the concrete value of x open?  I agree that what I am doing with the left-hand side is an abstraction, but I think that applying the argument immediately makes it something different.

Comment: I see what you mean. Btw, it looks like a [let-expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_expression).

Comment: Indeed. Closure conversion requires a similar transformation (the abstracted terms being the lambda-expressions with all free variables explicitly bound).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's called beta expansion. Usage examples: [Horwitz](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~horwitz/CS704-NOTES/1.LAMBDA-CALCULUS.html), [Miller](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Dale.Miller/lProlog/cse360/lectures/lect8.html), [Galbiati and Talcott](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RHR9VybZJ9kC&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347&dq=%22beta-expansion%22+%22beta-reduction%22&source=bl&ots=nMz9TKtID-&sig=mkDE8FrwEV4Cl3cSUVOwo9jVwvs&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22beta-expansion%22%20%22beta-reduction%22&f=false), [Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#Conversion-tactics), …

Similarly $M \to (\lambda x. M \, x)$ (the converse of eta reduction) is called eta expansion, and so on.